# NullReferenceException / ConnectionString возвращает null / MVC (C#) / Unit Test

Tags: c#, mvc, юнит-тесты

Здравствуйте.

Kто может мне помочь с UnitTest в C#/MVC?

Не понимаю как можно исправить Exception, идет от того что моя написанная программа (`UnitTest`) не полная.

Тестирую `Login()` функцию, задавая при входе "email" и "password", метод в Unit Test-е работает отдельно от проекта, и для этого нужно чтобы параллельно работал проект для связи с базой / Global.asax файл (5 рисунок)

[image: Global файл]

Возвращаемые значения "email" и "password" --> null (когда делаю дебаг), нет связи с сервером, и всегда генерируется

> Exception Message: "Test method UnitProject.UnitTest.TestLoginUser
>   threw exception: Ogma.Project.Common.Security.LoginException: There is
>   an error on server side."

Я думаю проблема в `ConnectionString` (2 рисунок)

[image: ConnectionString]

Во время дебага возвращает null (3 рисунок)

[image: ConnectionString возвращает null]

Но у меня есть `ConnectionString` (4 рисунок)

[image: у меня есть ConnectionString]

Тест написан для `AccountController`.
Код запускаемого теста (1 рисунок)

[image: Код запускаемого теста]

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите, в чём дело.

Когда ваше приложение запускается обычным образом, выполняется `Application_Start`, в котором происходит нужная настройка. Но в случае тестов, выполняется ваш код в контексте тестового приложения, и вам нужно проинициализироваться отдельно.

Для этого вы должны создать метод, в котором будет производиться настройка, и применить к нему один из атрибутов [`[AssemblyInitialize]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assemblyinitializeattribute.aspx), [`[ClassInitialize]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.classinitializeattribute.aspx) или [`[TestInitialize]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testinitializeattribute.aspx) в зависимости от того, хотите ли вы установить параметры для всей тестовой сборки, для одного класса или для одного теста (в вашем случае, судя по всему, имеет место первый вариант).

Кроме того, если вы хотите использовать *реальные* строки подключения (а зачем это для тестов?), вам придётся ещё и положить эти самые строки в место, доступное для теста. То есть, добавить `app.config` к вашему проекту, и перенести в него строку из `web.config` (наверное, всю секцию `connectionStrings`). Но скорее всего для тестов вам не нужно настоящее, «боевое» подключение, так что сюда скорее всего нужно будет положить специальную строку для тестового подключения.